# Not able to properly write excel file send over http in nodejs/Meteor

Tags: node.js, excel, file-upload, meteor

I am using Meteor application which has nodejs at the backend. I want my application to accept excel file send over http and write this excel to disk. My code looks as below.

```
HTTP.methods fileListener: (data) ->
    buffer = new Buffer(data, 'base64')
    binaryBuffer = buffer.toString('binary')

    fs = Npm.require("fs")
    fs.writeFileSync "ExcelSupportTest3.xlsx", binaryBuffer
```

This is coffeescript code. The excel file will be base64 encoded and send.

The problem here is that even though I could write the file to the disk, the file doesn't have the characters in proper format. It is full of junk characters which is not properly readable.

How can I properly send the data over http and have it in the correct format?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you achieved this anyhow ?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using this tool: https://www.npmjs.org/package/xlsx It goes with some basic examples which should be helpful.